# Spring web server could not load Cordapp. Fails to find the State class. Error - AMQ214000: Failed to call onMessage

Tags: corda

I am in process of migrating my cordapp from Corda v1.0 to Corda v4.0. I am following step-by-step migration method.

While migrating the cordapp from Corda v1.0 to Corda v2.0, the nodes get successfully deployed and run, but on running Springboot webserver, I am getting error - "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.corda.bgc.contract.State" in the node cmd window.

*[The nodes and webserver runs successully with Corda v1.0.]*

Following are the details of the error -

Springbootweb server after starting successfully, freezes
while connecting to CorDapp. Following is the stacktrace from web server cmd window -

```
I 17:50:49 1 Server.doStart - Started @29133ms
   I 17:50:54 1 RPCClient.logElapsedTime - Startup took 3682 msec
<==I 17:50:54 1 ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize - Initializing ExecutorService  'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
I 17:50:54 1 ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize - Initializing ExecutorService  'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
> :server:runMyCorpUSAServer
```

Following is the stacktrace from node cmd window -

```
Mon Jun 03 18:08:07 IST 2019>>> E 18:09:20+0530 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] core.client.run - AMQ214000: Failed to call onMessage
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.corda.bgc.contract.State
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.ClassSerializer.read(Kryo.kt:526) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.ClassSerializer.read(Kryo.kt:523) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$CollectionsSingletonListSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:577) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$CollectionsSingletonListSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:567) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:209) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:152) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.withContext(SerializationScheme.kt:191) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.access$withContext(SerializationScheme.kt:152) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1.execute(SerializationScheme.kt:206) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:61) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:205) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:115) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:53) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:115) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:95) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:67) ~[corda-core-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:115) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ClientToServer$Companion.fromClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:234) ~[corda-node-api-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:263) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.access$clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:76) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer$createConsumerSessions$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:189) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer$createConsumerSessions$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:76) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServerKt$sam$MessageHandler$b852d39b.onMessage(RPCServer.kt) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:997) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:49) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1120) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:101) [artemis-commons-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

Kindly provide insights regarding above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The version of the CorDapp jar that Spring is using does not seem to be the same one that the Corda node is using. Have you recompiled the web server code? Have you moved the state to a different location? Basically no class def found is synchronisation issue between the server and node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved by copying cordapp jar file into "plugins" directory of each node.

In Corda V1, the copying of cordapp jar file to "plugins" directory of each node was done by the process whereas in Corda V2, it seems we have to do it manually. Please correct me if I am wrong.